# Jar файл проекта не содержит зависимости(не запускается без среды разработки)

Tags: java, linux, gradle, jar, зависимости

Привожу в порядок старый Open Source проект. Решил со сборки `Ant` перевести на `Gradle`. Некоторые библиотеки подтянул из `mvnCentral`, некоторые сам написал и загрузил на `GitHub`, через `JitPuck` подтягиваю в проект.
Проблема состоит в том, что при запуске из `jar` файла, через `linux-терминал`, он выводит ошибку:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class org.opensourcephysics.cabrillo.tracker.Tracker
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opensourcephysics/display/OSPFrame
```

Сам проект с классом `org/opensourcephysics/display/OSPFrame` подтягиваются через зависимости `JitPack`. Понять не могу в чем проблема, так как через среду разработки собирается и запускается без проблем. Разархивировал сам `jar`, а там только файлы и классы проекта Tracker(непосредственно, мой проект).

Gradle:

```java
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        // This is where the Main class is specified for launching applications (otherwise the jar will not start)
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.opensourcephysics.cabrillo.tracker.Tracker'
    }
}

group 'org.osptracker'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // Added JitPack for working with dependencies via GitHub
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.nativelibs4java', name: 'bridj', version: '0.7.0'

    implementation 'com.github.OpenSource-Physics-Tracker:AppleJavaExstensions:70fb48e5fe'
    implementation 'com.github.OpenSource-Physics-Tracker:OpenSourcePhysics:0770a07'
    implementation 'com.github.OpenSource-Physics-Tracker:FFMpeg:ef6949741c'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
}
```

Как видно, среда разработки подтягивает данную библиотеку через зависимости:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, сам проект не запускается, так как жалуется NoClassDefFoundError на класс библиотеки `org.opensourcephysics`, хотя данная библиотека успешно добавлена в проект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

то что jar проекта содержит только файлы проекта - это норм.
если нужно создать запускаемый jar со всеми зависимостями, т.н. fat-jar, то это уже описано к примеру [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278063/how-do-i-create-an-executable-fat-jar-with-gradle-with-implementation-dependenci)